# Insert word in the middle of text for every multiples of 4

Tags: sed

Text:

```
exampleexampleexampleexample
```

Desired output:

```
exam$plee$xamp$leex$ampl$eexa$mpl$
```

I did this:

```
sed 's/[^*]/&$/4'
```

But it doesn't work, is there another way to do it?

Comment: answer to [now deleted question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/536772/72456): `echo 'something' | sed 's/.\{'$(( ( RANDOM % MAX) +MIN ))'\}/&$/g'` (_replace MAX with a max number and MIN with min number_); no you cannot easily revert that back if the `$` character was previously can find in your input else `... | sed 's/\$//g'`

Comment: Now it's work @αғsнιη thx 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert `$` globally after four characters:

```
$ echo "exampleexampleexampleexample" | sed 's/.\{4\}/&$/g'
exam$plee$xamp$leex$ampl$eexa$mple$
```

The `.` matches one character and `.\{4\}` matches four of them. The replacement part `&$` consists of the matched pattern `&` (four characters) and `$`. Using the `g` flag, the pattern is replaced globally (every four characters).

Comment: Thanks It's work @Freddy, could you explain it for me?

Comment: Okay, and if I want to revert back and delete that $? @Freddy

Comment: Reversed: `echo 'exam$plee$xamp$leex$ampl$eexa$mple$' | sed 's/\(.\{4\}\)\$/\1/g'`